# Unexpected parent reaction to child button Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, parent-child

I have a ImportCsvRiskAssessmentComponent child component. The parent component is add-risk-assessment. When I click on the "Import" button of the child component, the onSubmitAddRiskAssessment() function is launched. And it's true for any button that I create in the child component, even if thay don't have a (click) attribute.

Can you please help me to understand why ?

import-csv-risk-assessment.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="showRiskAssassmentCsvForm">
  <div class="mb-3 row">
    <label for="csvFile" class="form-label">Select Risk Assessment csv file :</label>
    <input type="file" id="csvFile" accept=".csv" (change)="onFileChange($event)">
  </div>
  <button id="submitRiskAssessmentCsv" class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-2" (click)="importRiskAssessmentCsv()" [disabled]="csvFile === undefined">Import</button>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" (click)="cancelRiskAssessmentImport()">Cancel Import</button>
  
</div>
<div *ngIf="message" class="alert alert-success">
  {{message}}
</div>
```

import-csv-risk-assessment.component.ts

```
export class ImportCsvRiskAssessmentComponent {
  @Output() riskAssessmentFromRiskAssessmentCsv = new EventEmitter<RiskAssessmentModel>();
  @Output() cancelRiskAssessmentCsvImport = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  @ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput: any;

  riskAssessment = new RiskAssessmentModel('NewRiskAssessment','', 0, 1, '', [],);
  csvFile: any;
  message!: string;

  isRiskAssessmentCsvSubmitted = false;
  showRiskAssassmentCsvForm = true;


  constructor(private ngxCsvParser: NgxCsvParser) {}

  public importRiskAssessmentCsv(): void {
      this.isRiskAssessmentCsvSubmitted = true;
      this.sendParametersFromCSV(this.csvFile);
  }

  public onFileChange(event: any): void {
    this.csvFile = event.target.files[0];
    console.log("onfile change", this.csvFile);
  }

  public sendParametersFromCSV(csvFile: any) {
    ...
  }

[...]

  public cancelRiskAssessmentImport() {
    const importRiskAssessmentCSV = false;
    this.cancelRiskAssessmentCsvImport.emit(importRiskAssessmentCSV);
  }
}
```

add-risk-assessment.component.html

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-delete-riskAssessment">Add Risk Assessment</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <form [formGroup]="newRAForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitAddRiskAssessment()">
    <div class="mb-3 row">
      <label for="csvFile" class="form-label">Risk Assessment name :</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" formControlName="name">
      <div *ngIf="newRAForm.get('name')?.status === 'INVALID'&&
          (newRAForm.get('name')?.dirty ||
          newRAForm.get('name')?.touched) ||
          isSubmitted">
        <app-validation-errors [errors]="newRAForm.get('name')?.errors"></app-validation-errors>      
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- For csv dataset parameters names import -->
    <div class="mb-3 row" *ngIf="!importCSV">
      <button (click)="activeImport()" class="btn btn-outline-primary" [disabled]="importRiskAssessmentCSV">Import parameters from .csv dataset</button>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3 row" *ngIf="importCSV">
      <app-import-csv-dataset (tableDataFromCsv)="onTableDataFromCsv($event)"
                              (datasetName)="onDatasetNameFromCsv($event)"
                              (cancelCsvImport)="onCancelCsvImport($event)">
      </app-import-csv-dataset>
    </div>

    <!-- For riskAssessment from .csv RiskAssessment import -->
    <div id="importRiskAssessmentCsvDiv">
      <div class="mb-3 row" *ngIf="!importRiskAssessmentCSV">
        <button (click)="activeRiskAssessmentCsvImport()" class="btn btn-outline-primary" [disabled]="importCSV">Import risk assessment from .csv risk assessment</button>
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3 row" *ngIf="importRiskAssessmentCSV">
          <app-import-csv-risk-assessment (riskAssessmentFromRiskAssessmentCsv)="onRiskAssessmentFromCsv($event)"
                                      (cancelRiskAssessmentCsvImport)="onCancelRiskAssessmentCsvImport($event)">
          </app-import-csv-risk-assessment>
      </div>  
    </div>


    <button class="btn btn-primary m-2" type="submit" [disabled]="newRAForm.invalid">Add Risk Assessment</button>
    <button (click)="cancelAddRA()" class="btn btn-outline-danger m-2" type="submit">Cancel</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

add-risk-assessment.component.ts

```
export class AddRiskAssessmentComponent {

  @Output() addNewRiskAssessment: EventEmitter<RiskAssessmentModel> = new EventEmitter<RiskAssessmentModel>();
  @Output() hideAddRAForm = new EventEmitter();


  newRiskAssessment = new RiskAssessmentModel('NewRiskAssessment','', 0, 1, '', []);

  newRAForm: FormGroup;
  isSubmitted = false;
  // For table data parameters names from csv dataset import
  importCSV = false;

  // For tableData from csv risk assessment tableData import
  importTableDataCSV = false;

  // For riskAssessement from csv risk assessment tableData import
  importRiskAssessmentCSV = false;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
                this.newRAForm = this.formBuilder.group({
                  name: ['', Validators.required]
                })
  }

  public onSubmitAddRiskAssessment(): void {
    this.isSubmitted = true;
    if (this.newRAForm.valid) {
      const formData = this.newRAForm.value;
      // console.log('ligne ajoutee', formData);
      this.newRiskAssessment.name = formData.name;
      console.log("ONSUBMIT", this.newRiskAssessment);

      // Emit changes to parent risk-assessment
      this.addNewRiskAssessment.emit(this.newRiskAssessment);

      this.isSubmitted = false;

    } else {
      // Handling of validation errors, e.g. display of an error message
      console.log('Le formulaire est invalide. Veuillez corriger les erreurs.');
      const controls = this.newRAForm.controls;
      for (const name in controls) {
          if (controls[name].invalid) {
            console.log("controles {{name}}", name, controls[name]);
          }
      }
    }
  }

[...]

  // Import RiskAssessment from RiskAssessment csv file
  public onRiskAssessmentFromCsv(riskAssessment: RiskAssessmentModel): void {
    this.newRiskAssessment = riskAssessment;
  }

  public activeRiskAssessmentCsvImport() {
    this.importRiskAssessmentCSV = true;
  }

  public onCancelRiskAssessmentCsvImport(importRACSV: boolean): void {
    console.log("AddRACompoNewRAAOnCancelRiskassessmentCsvImport",this.newRiskAssessment);
    this.importRiskAssessmentCSV = importRACSV;
  }

  public cancelAddRA() {
    this.hideAddRAForm.emit()
  }
}
```

I expect the "Import" button to only call the importRiskAssessmentCsv() function of the child component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here can be your some other buttons have been set with type="submit" and when you click on them, it will trigger to submit the form (ngSubmit event waiting for that) and then function onSubmitAddRiskAssessment() will be active.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but what I don't understand is that my cancel button doesn't cause this. And I don't know which attribute of my input button causes this reaction, I've tried adding other buttons, and even when they don't have an attribute (click) it calls the parent component's function.

Answer (score 0):

By just specifying the type, it seems to solve the problem.

type="button"

Love spending hours to finally solve the problem with 13 characters..